# The story of a div's unaccounted space

Tags: html, css

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn1m813w/10/) tells the story of a lonely `div`. One day, an inline `img` visited the lonely `div`. They became good friends. But no matter what the `img` did, it was never quite able to fill the `div`'s void, and thus the lonely `div` remained depressed:

HTML:

```
<div><img src="..."></img></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {

    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px; 
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Say, who can cure the `div` of it's feeling of emptiness?

Update: The original fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wn1m813w/).

Comment: Put `display:block` to the `svg`?

Comment: That seems to work! But why?

Comment: Can you post this as an answer? It also fixes other related issues I had :)

Comment: have them sit on a table `svg {display: table;}`?

Comment: @OzgurBar That works too. But why does `display: inline` not work?

Comment: Where is the `svg` that everyone's talking about?

Comment: @Danield look at the [old fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn1m813w/).

Comment: umm did you change the fiddle? (edit:aha!)

Comment: I did :) The `svg` issue was not accurately mirroring my actual `img` issue.

Comment: @Domi it's the width and height attributes actually, they're deprecated. if you changed the markup into this `<rect style="width:16px;height:16px;"`, it would have worked.

Comment: @OzgurBar Ok! But that does not explain why `display: block` fixes the [img problem](http://jsfiddle.net/wn1m813w/10/)?

Comment: I think, it might have to do with the line height set in the bootstrap css file. E.g. if you set the line-height for the div to 0px it also works without setting the image to block-level.

Comment: Right: `display: inline` is affected by `line-height`... I tried setting it to `16px`, but that did not work. I think, [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) does some weird things sometimes...

Comment: btw, i think your problem was the extra margin below svg since the beginning?

Comment: @Domi why not just tell the `img` to take full width&height of its parent - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn1m813w/12/)?

Comment: With 3.7k rep you know better than to not include any code with your fiddle links in your questions. Especially when the main fiddle link is going to change over the course of the question. I'll leave it up to you to figure out which code needs to go into the question.

Comment: @Domi: I think the main cause of your problem was that the div with `inline-block` specified was causing an extra space after `svg` element. so use `font-size:0;` in div's css in the original fiddle.

Comment: @OzgurBar Another useful idea! Thanks a lot! You want to post an answer, summarizing all that?

Comment: the question is on hold, but it's ok, glad that worked:]

Comment: @BoltClock To be honest, I did that many times. But until now, it simply would not let me, reminding me with a RED error message that I must include code snippets! I think, they are messing with the code today. Had some bugs with links today as well? Anyway, it's fixed now :)

Comment: @Vucko Because that will mess with the aspect ratio

Comment: @OzgurBar It has been un-on-holded. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed in your jsfiddle when I add "line-height: 0" to the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

The image is `display: inline-block` which takes into account white space and line height.  I suggest adding `vertical-align: top;` to the image's style rule.

```
img {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y7dd2qmx/